# How to install active support with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I have setup ruby and rails using rbenv.

```
$ which ruby
~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
$ which rails
~/.rbenv/shims/rails
```

I want to install two gems i.e. `activesupport` and `i18n`. Is the procedure same i.e. Go to terminal> type the following:

```
$gem install activesupport 
$gem install i18n
```

or for rbenv manager there is some other way? I don't want to break anything.

*Details:*

```
rbenv version 0.4.0. 
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use a Gemfile in the directory of the project I am working on.

Your Gemfile might look like

```
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'i18n'
```

Then run

```
$ bundle install
```

This will pull the latest versions of these gems and save them according to your defined `rbenv`.

Not only that. In terms of your concerns about "breaking things", when you run `bundle install` a `Gemfile.lock` file will be created detailing the current versions of the gems used **specific** to the project of the directory you are working in.

Comment: I not using any IDE like RubyMines etc. I want to practice this in single ruby file. In any directory globally. To use these gem files I want that all I need to do is `require 'activesupport/all'`

Comment: This is all straight from the command line ... No IDE here. Here is a great summary of using `rbenv` with `bundler`: https://cbednarski.com/articles/installing-ruby/