# In Ruby, how to add active_support/core_ext/time?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, activesupport

I found some Ruby code that made use of:

```rb
require "active_support/core_ext/time"
require "active_support/core_ext/numeric"
```

On my Mac with macOS Monterey, I don't have rails or `rvm` yet, and if I install `rvm`, it requires Homebrew to install a new Ruby and it may complicate things further, so with the system Ruby (`ruby 2.6.8p205`), how can `active_support/core_ext/time` be installed so that it can be used?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314415/how-to-install-active-support-with-rbenv) and it doesn't solve the problem.

I recalled I can install rails:

```sh
gem install rails
```

However, is it true that I have to use `sudo` to do it? (I try to minimize the use of `sudo` to keep the system more secure).

Comment: You can install `active_support`, or any other gem for that matter, without `sudo` too. See here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421449

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45347703/823617

Comment: If you are willing to modify the source code of this program that you are using, it is possible to convert it to use Bundler. In that case there is no need to install any system gems at all. You would just use Bundler, and it would take care of adding the required dependencies locally into the app itself. (N.B. assuming Bundler exists in your current Ruby installation).

Answer (score 2):

Using `sudo` to install a gem is completely a bad idea.

It's better to use some Ruby manager in your system.

For example:

- [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf)
- [RVM](https://github.com/rvm/rvm)
- [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)
- [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)

You can also use [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) to isolate the project.

When you get some Ruby using one of these variants, you can install the ActiveSupport gem with `Gemfile` or just with as terminal command:

```
gem install activesupport
```

Then you can choose file(s) that will be required here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/main/activesupport/lib

For example, you need all `Time` monkeypatches.

There are in *[time.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time.rb)*.

So you need to use:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/time"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing using

`sudo gem install active_support`

You have to use sudo because you are writing to a default system library.

**I would highly recommend using [RBEnv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rbenv) or [RVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_Version_Manager)**, so you aren't meddling with the system Ruby constantly. It is slightly more setup, but both [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) and RVM are well known and supported libraries.

Comment: so I just have to bite the bullet and install Homebrew as well I think?  thanks so much

Comment: Yes, it really isn't too bad and plays pretty nice with the default system so you shouldn't have too much trouble.

Comment: I have used rvm before but not rbenv... I just read the README of rbenv and it looks like that's why a lot of software engineers work overtime

Comment: **DO NOT, EVER, UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCE, MODIFY APPLE'S RUBY INSTALLATION. IF YOU EVER NEED TO USE SUDO TO INSTALL A GEM, YOU ARE DOING IT WRONG. IF YOU EVER FIND SOMEONE TELLING YOU TO DO USE SUDO TO INSTALL A GEM, IGNORE THEM.**

Comment: There are two big problems in this answer: 1. `sudo` (never use it to install gems). 2. `active_support` (there is no such gem). Therefore the only correct part of `sudo gem install active_support` command is `gem install`

Comment: @JörgWMittag I trust you, but can you add a statement as to why not modify Apple's Ruby installation? For example, if we update XCode or Final Cut or GarageBand, it is all ok, so why not Ruby?

Comment: The correct name of the gem is `activesupport`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [mechnicov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277832/in-ruby-how-to-add-active-support-core-ext-time/72281335#72281335), yes, first install something like [RVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_Version_Manager), and then

```
gem install activesupport
```

And you can use

```
require "active_support/core_ext/time"
```

as before (which supposedly loads everything in *[time.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time.rb)*)

If you are using a recent version of Ruby, depending on what you need in numeric, instead of:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/numeric"
```

which supposedly loads *[numeric.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric.rb)*, you can use:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb"
```

as in the [Ruby on Rails documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html).

You can also include everything by:

```
require "active_support/all"
```

as in [this Ruby on Rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html).  See *[all.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/all.rb)* for details.